# Update a column based on another column conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a typical requirement to validate a Column value[Target] against the Boundary values specified as min and max in other columns in the same Table.

Currently, I am doing the validation in 2 steps and making sure the target column value lies within the boundary limits. Can this be done with a single Update statement?

Below is the test data set:

```
CREATE TABLE rr_test
(
    minlimit INTEGER,
    maxlimit INTEGER,
    actualval INTEGER,
    calcval INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO rr_test
     VALUES (0,
             1000,
             500,
             NULL);

INSERT INTO rr_test
     VALUES (0,
             1000,
             2000,
             NULL);

INSERT INTO rr_test
     VALUES (2000,
             0,
             50,
             NULL);

INSERT INTO rr_test
     VALUES (2000,
             0,
             4000,
             NULL);

INSERT INTO rr_test
     VALUES (0,
             2000,
             50,
             NULL);

INSERT INTO rr_test
     VALUES (2000,
             4000,
             5000,
             NULL);

INSERT INTO rr_test
     VALUES (2000,
             4000,
             1000,
             NULL);

INSERT INTO rr_test
     VALUES (2000,
             4000,
             2000,
             NULL);

INSERT INTO rr_test
     VALUES (2000,
             4000,
             4000,
             NULL);

--To compare final results
UPDATE rr_test
   SET calcval = actualval;
```

Dataset at this point:

```
MINLIMIT    MAXLIMIT    ACTUALVAL     CALCVAL
0           1000            500         500
0           1000            2000        2000
2000        0               50          50
2000        0               4000        4000
0           2000            50          50
2000        4000            5000        5000
2000        4000            1000        1000
2000        4000            2000        2000
2000        4000            4000        4000 

--Update Target with Max Boundary
UPDATE rr_test
   SET calcval = maxlimit
 WHERE actualval > maxlimit;

--Update Target with Min Boundary
UPDATE rr_test
   SET calcval = minlimit
 WHERE calcval < minlimit;
```

Final Dataset:

```
MINLIMIT    MAXLIMIT    ACTUALVAL     CALCVAL
  0           1000        500           500
  0           1000        2000          1000
  2000        0           50            2000
  2000        0           4000          2000
  0           2000        50            50
  2000        4000        5000          4000
  2000        4000        1000          2000
  2000        4000        2000          2000
  2000        4000        4000          4000
```

Comment: How can you have a situation in which the `minlimit` is greater than the `maxlimit`? That makes a nonsense of the range concept. Or have you omitted to tell us about the special rule for handling `0`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
UPDATE rr_test
   SET actualval =
        CASE
            WHEN actualval < minlimit THEN minlimit
            WHEN actualval > maxlimit THEN maxlimit
            ELSE actualval
        END;
```

Comment: The requirement is for an UPDATE statement not a SELECT

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```
UPDATE rr_test
SET calcval = CASE WHEN actualval > maxlimit THEN maxlimit
                   WHEN actualval < minlimit THEN minlimit END
WHERE
    actualval > maxlimit OR
    actualval < minlimit
```

I think this reproduces the logic of your original two updates.  If the first update happened, then the second one would never happen.  The second update could only happen if the first did not.  The above `CASE` expression has the same behavior, since only condition can occur with each update.

Edit - if both conditions fire on the same row:

```
UPDATE rr_test
SET calcval = CASE WHEN actualval < minlimit THEN minlimit 
                   WHEN actualval > maxlimit THEN maxlimit END
WHERE
    actualval > maxlimit OR
    actualval < minlimit
```

Comment: @mathguy Thanks for the edit, I think a single update is possible, though this assumes the OP's two updates were actually correct to begin with.

Comment: Works good when I ensure maxlimit is always greater than minlimit, but sometimes it is not the case as I observed in test data.  Row 3 and Row 4 test data fails with above query. I was making sure with 2 updates that minlimit is always respected.

Comment: @Rupesh I assumed in my answer that the max limit is always greater than the min limit.  Is this not a reasonable assumption?

Comment: If the two updates could fire on the same row, then I don't think you can easily get them into a single statement.   In that case, you could still run them in a single transaction though.

Comment: True, I was just thinking if there was any possibility to tackle this  in a single statement :)

Comment: I don't see a way to do this, because each of your 2 updates might be overwriting the `calcval` column.  A single `UPDATE` can only write to the same column once.

Comment: if both updates would fire on the same row, the effect will be the same as just the second update happening.  so switching the order of the case statement should have the same effect (edited answer)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a situation that does this in Single statement with the hints from above queries respecting all cases of Min and Max limits:

```
UPDATE rr_test
   SET actualval =
           CASE
               WHEN maxlimit > minlimit
               THEN
                   CASE
                       WHEN actualval > maxlimit THEN maxlimit
                       WHEN actualval < minlimit THEN minlimit
                       ELSE actualval
                   END
               WHEN maxlimit < minlimit
               THEN
                   minlimit
               WHEN maxlimit = minlimit
               THEN
                   CASE
                       WHEN actualval > maxlimit THEN maxlimit
                       WHEN actualval < maxlimit THEN minlimit
                       ELSE actualval
                   END
           END;
```

Comment: But in practice I wouldn't use this, because it is verbose and difficult to maintain.  Rather, I would just use two separate updates in a single transaction.

Comment: The other two branches could be simplified to when `maxlimit <= minlimit then minlimit`. But this exercise seems rather ropey: you should have check constraints in place to ensure that `actualval` is populated correctly.

Comment: 100% agreed, even I am going with 2 separate updates due to the complexity around the CASE statements for future teams to understand this logic.